# Method chaining in Javascript in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

in my Angular web app, I have a module called `ApplicationModule`.
`ApplicationModule` has `get` and `set` functions.

In one of my controllers, I call function like below:

```
ApplicationModule.get().then(function (response) {
    //do something with response
});
```

`GET()` function returns an object called `application`. With the returned object, I would like to do something with it. so I use `then` to chain the method but I get an error saying `angular.js:13424 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Updated what get() is.

```
ApplicationModule.get = function () {
        if (!localStorage.application) {
            Restangular.all('session').one('user').get().then(function (response) {
                      application = {
                                    "id": response.current_application_id,
                                    "user_id": response.id,
                                    "visa_type": response.current_type
                                    }
                localStorage.setItem("application", JSON.stringify(application));
                return application
            });
        } else {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.application)
        }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `.then()` is usually only used for promise syntax. Your `.get()` method doesn't return a promise, it returns an object. Just do `var response = ApplicationModule.get();`

Comment: Well apparently `.get()` does *not* return an object. You'll have to show us its code though if you want us to help you fix the problem.

Comment: It sounds like ApplicationModule.get does not exists (is undefined). Are you sure its not GET()?  Also it needs to be returning a promise.

Comment: you aren't showing what `get()` returns, only describing that it is supposed to be returning an `application` object.  To troubleshoot the problem, it would be necessary to see the full signature of the `get()` method.

Comment: I just need to call certain function after ApplicationModule.get() is fully run. `ApplicationModule.get()` and other function should be sequential in order not to cause a problem in my app. And `get()` just returns an object which is a JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method does [neither `return` the `application`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/1048572) nor does it return an object at all if `localStorage.application` is falsy.

You are doing something asynchronous in your function, so you need to always return a promise:

```
ApplicationModule.get = function () {
    if (!localStorage.application) {
        return Rectangular.all('session').one('user').get().then(function (response) {
//      ^^^^^^ returning the promise
            var application = {
                "id": response.current_application_id,
                "user_id": response.id,
                "visa_type": response.current_type
            };
            localStorage.setItem("application", JSON.stringify(application));
            return application;
//          ^^^^^^ returning the value that the promise will resolve with
        });
    } else {
        return $q.resolve(JSON.parse(localStorage.application));
//             ^^^^^^^^^^ creating a promise here as well for consistent interface
    }
}
```

Comment: what does `return Restangular` does? and what does `$q.resolve` do? Never encountered this so I would appreciate your further explanation.

Comment: @JoHksi `Restangular` is just a typo on Bergi's part, you should follow the link he provided in "neither return the application". [`$q.resolve`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#resolve) just signals to the calling function that the promise returned by `ApplicationModule.get()` finished successfully.

Comment: @peteb, are you suggesting to delete return in front of Restangular then? And how do I write additional function to catch errors? on `ApplicationModule.get()`?

Comment: @JoHksi no I'm not, that is exactly what has been causing your problem, the lack of you returning the promise created by `Rectangular.all()`. Read the comments in the snippet provided by Bergi...

Comment: @JoHksi: No, we're not suggesting to omit the `return` - the whole point of my answer is that you forgot it in your original code! It does return the promise that the `.then(…)` call returns.

Comment: @Bergi, gotcha! on the `ApplicationModule.get()` itself, after calling `then`, how can I catch the error?

Comment: @JoHksi by using a `.catch()` function in your promise chain after your `.then()`

Comment: @JoHksi: Just chain a `.catch(function(err) { … })` to it, like for any promise.

Comment: thank you so much all :) It would be great to see if you guys have any link for more explaining about promise. Not very familiar with this concept :)

Comment: @peteb, i all of sudden started getting an errror saying `ReferenceError: $q is not defined` not sure why :/

Comment: @JoHksi You need to add it as a dependency to inject into your `ApplicationModule`, `angular.module('ApplicationModule', ['$q', function($q) {}]);`

Comment: @JoHksi: I've used the [`$q` module](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24q) implicitly, given your question is tagged [tag:angular-promise] I thought you were already using it.

Comment: Thank you all! Really appreciate both of you .

Comment: @Bergi, I have one more question. Is there a way to return `JSON.parse(localStorage.application)` without putting it in $q.resolve()? ApplicationModule.get() is made to return application object, but if `JSON.parse(localStorage.application)` is embedded in`$q.resolve()`, it returns promise object and makes me hard to utilize it.

Comment: @JoHksi: No, that is not possible. In fact, `get()` being made to always return a promise for the application object makes it much easier to utilise than if it sometimes did return the object directly and sometimes did return a promise for it (when it needs to fetch if from Rectangular). If you always return a promise, you are guaranteed to always get your result asynchronusly, and this consistency simplifies async programming a huge lot.

Answer (score 0):

The method `.then()` is only applicable to promises. In order to do something with your application object I suggest storing the value as a variable.

```
var application = ApplicationModule.get();
foo(application);
```

Comment: this does not work for my app. please check out my comment above.